# how to change the color of a row of a table on hover

Tags: css

I am trying to change the color of a row of a table on hover.
by using row: hover, but by this way it is just hovering a perticular cell which is obvious.
but when I try using `row cell: hover`, then it is not having any effect. this is my html.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4ojhxco/2/

```
 <div id="table">
  <div class="header-row row">
<span class="cell">SI. No.</span>
    <span class="cell">Application Date</span>
    <span class="cell">Customer Name</span>
    <span class="cell">Loan Amount</span>
    <span class="cell">Loan Status</span>
    <span class="cell">Action</span>
  </div>
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of customerList ; let i= index;">
    <input type="radio" name="expand">
<span class="cell" data-label="SI. No.">{{i+1}}</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Application Date">{{item.date}}</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Customer Name">
  {{item.name}}</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Loan Amount">{{item.amount}}</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Loan Status">{{item.status}}</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Action">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">More Details</a>
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add working example in code pen or fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f4ojhxco/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give the style as follows by removing the space between the class `.row` and `:hover`.

```
.row:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `!important` keyword.

```
  .row :hover {
    background: green !important;
  }
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4ojhxco/3/

Comment: !Important isn't necessary in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#table .row:hover {
 /*add your css here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
 body {
   background: #cacaca;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
   font-weight: 300;
 }

 #table {
   display: table;
    width: 100%;
   background: #fff;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .caption {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   background: #64e0ef;
   height: 55px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 55px;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .header-row {
   background: #8b8b8b;
   color: #fff;
 }

 .row {
   display: table-row;
  }

  .row :hover {
    background: green;
  }



 .cell {
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 23px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
   text-align: center;
 }

 .primary {
   text-align: left;
 }

 input[type="radio"],
 input[type="checkbox"] {
   display: none;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
   body {
     padding: 0;
   }
   #table {
     display: block;
     margin: 44px 0 0 0;
   }
   .caption {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     text-align: center;
     height: 44px;
     line-height: 44px;
     z-index: 5;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
   }
   .row {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
   .header-row {
     display: none;
   }
   .cell {
     display: block;
     border: none;
     position: relative;
     height: 45px;
     line-height: 45px;
     text-align: left;
   }
   .primary:after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     right: 20px;
     top: 18px;
     z-index: 2;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-top: 10px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
     border-right: 10px solid #ccc;
   }
   .cell:nth-of-type(n+2) {
     display: none;
   }
   input[type="radio"],
   input[type="checkbox"] {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 99%;
     height: 100%;
     opacity: 0;
   }
   input[type="radio"]:checked,
   input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
     z-index: -1;
   }
   input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell,
   input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell {
     display: block;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
   }
   input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2),
   input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2) {
     background: #e0e0e0;
   }
   input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2):before,
   input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2):before {
     content: attr(data-label);
     display: inline-block;
     width: 60px;
     background: #999;
     border-radius: 10px;
     height: 20px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 20px;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
   }
   input[type="radio"]:checked~.primary,
   input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.primary {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
   }
   input[type="radio"]:checked~.primary:after,
   input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.primary:after {
     position: absolute;
     right: 18px;
     top: 22px;
     border-right: 10px solid transparent;
     border-left: 10px solid transparent;
     border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
     z-index: 2;
   }
 }
  .cell{
    height:10px;
    background:green;
    
  }
  .cell:hover{
    background:red;
  }
```

```html
 <div id="table">
  <div class="header-row row">
<span class="cell">SI. No.</span>
    <span class="cell">Application Date</span>
    <span class="cell">Customer Name</span>
    <span class="cell">Loan Amount</span>
    <span class="cell">Loan Status</span>
    <span class="cell">Action</span>
  </div>
<div class="row" >
    <input type="radio" name="expand">
<span class="cell" data-label="SI. No.">1</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Application Date">5-jan-2017</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Customer Name">
  mr xyz</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Loan Amount">60k</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Loan Status">open</span>
<span class="cell" data-label="Action">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">More Details</a>
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove space between `.row` and `:hover`

```
.row:hover{
    background: green;
}
```